# How do I stop/pause the fetching of mail in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, spam-prevention

I have an account in Thunderbird which has not been checked for a long time (I've been using Gmail, which doesn't delete any messages from the server). So this means when I click "Get Mail" it starts fetching 2500+ emails!

I'm wondering, how do I stop or pause all those mails coming in? I have it set so it doesn't pull them in automatically on startup. But once I've clicked "Get Mail" there does not seem to be a way to stop it, besides quitting Thunderbird entirely.

My main motivation for wanting to pause fetching is that a lot of the email is spam so I'd like to pause and mark a bunch of emails as spam, then continue fetching with hopefully further email being marked as spam automatically.

Comment: Luckily BigSn already gave you a nice simple answer. Anything more elaborate will cost you more time than just letting all the mails come in and then handle that. Just sorting them differently is a quick way to detect a large percentage of the spam, then delete it with a selection + Del.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interrupt the process by clicking the little computer-icon in the lower left corner of the main window of Thunderbird.

A secondary click will re-enable the download process.

Comment: Thanks. A bit of a kludge, but it works.